# Count records in each category

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, aggregate-functions

I have two tables:

`ci_categories`
with fields `cat_id`, `cat_name`, `cat_slug` etc.

`ci_albums`
with fields `cat_id`, `album_id`, `album_name` etc.

I want to join these two tables, display category listing, and COUNT albums in each category. Like:

- Category 1 - 20 Albums
- Category 2 - 25 Albums

How is this done properly in PostgreSQL?

Comment: Which columns do you need in the result? Can there be categories without any albums?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query should get you what you want:

```
SELECT c.cat_id, COUNT(a.album_id)
FROM ci_categories AS c
LEFT JOIN ci_albums AS a ON c.cat_id = a.cat_id
GROUP BY c.cat_id
```

We use a `LEFT JOIN` here due to the possibility of categories which contain no albums.  If you don't care if those results show up, just change this to an `INNER JOIN`.

We use the aggregate `COUNT(a.album_id)` function to count the number of records.  By grouping by the `c.cat_id`, we make sure this count is done only over records of the same type.  If there is no album for that category, a.album_id will be NULL, and so `COUNT` will not include it in the total count.

Comment: and how to select cat_name?

Comment: Just add c.cat_name after c.cat_id in both the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` sections.

Answer (score 0):

```
select c.cat_name, 
       count(distinct a.album_id) as albums
from ci_categories c
left join ci_albums a on a.cat_id = c.cat_id
group by c.cat_name
```

Comment: we need also, cat_id? how we can get?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ci_categories.cat_name, COUNT(*) as count

FROM ci_categories JOIN ci_albums ON ci_categories.cat_id = ci_albums.cat_id

GROUP BY ci_categories.cat_name;
```

The other answers are somewhat equal with some slight differences, notably the `DISTINCT` in the `COUNT` and the aliasing of the tables.

EDIT / WARNING

Well, my answer is actually wrong, due to the fact that a `JOIN` will also include a categories if there are no albums in that category. That category is then joined to `NULL` values, which are counted by `COUNT(*)` anyways. Leaving this one here as an example of a common mistake.

Comment: You are wrong.  An inner join will not include categories if there are no albums.  A left outer join would.

Answer (score 0):

If you are satisfied with `cat_id` and the count of albums in the result, you don't need the table `ci_categories` in your query at all. Use this simpler and faster query:

```
SELECT cat_id, count(*) AS albums
FROM   ci_albums
GROUP  BY 1;
```

Assuming proper table definitions without duplicate entries.

This does not includes categories with no albums at all. Only if you need those - too, or if you need additional information from the table `ci_categories` itself - only then you need to join to that table. But since we are counting *everything*, it is faster to *aggregate first* and join later:

```
SELECT c.cat_id, c.cat_name, COALESCE(a.albums, 0) AS albums
FROM   ci_categories c
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT cat_id, count(*) AS albums
   FROM   ci_albums
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) a USING (cat_id);
```

[`LEFT JOIN`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-FROM) if you want categories with 0 albums, too. Else, just `JOIN`.
[`COALESCE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) is only needed if you need `0` instead of `NULL` in the result.
Test performance with [`EXPLAIN ANALYZE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-explain.html) if you care.